# Died or had died?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> Two years have passed since my cousin **had** died

or

> Two years have passed since my cousin died .

Which is correct?

Comment: Only one is grammatically correct, but the commas don’t belong in either one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct one is:

> Two years have passed since my cousin died.

The past-perfect tense is usually combined only with simple past or other past-perfect clauses. Combining present perfect and past perfect in the same sentence requires creating an extremely complex sentence with many clauses and tense combinations.

**Edit:** Because the OP requested an example, here is a possible sentence that contains both present perfect and past perfect:

> I **had been** a bright-eyed optimist before my cousin died, but ever since then, I **have thought** that the world is a terrible place.

It didn't turn out quite as complex as I was thinking, but do note that a minimum of three tenses are required in such a sentence—a past event (in past tense), a condition that preceded it (in the past perfect), and a condition that began after it and has continued ever since (in the present perfect).

Comment: One could write: _Two years had passed since my cousin had died,_ but the reader would be expecting something to follow – such as: _Two years had passed since my cousin had died, when the attorney came sauntering up our driveway_. (It’s not necessarily “extremely complex;” it can be used to provide a chronological setting.)

Comment: Can you given an example where we use present perfect and past perfect together?

Comment: @J.R. Yes, but that is two past-perfect clauses. Not past perfect and present perfect together.

Comment: Zephyr I almost added an example when I wrote this, but I was worried it would be off-topic. Since you say it would help you, I'll add an example to the answer.